# How to update element's class dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
     <div class="form-group">            
        <button type="submit"id="form_submit">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up
        </button>            
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="click_login">Already signed up! Then  Login</a>
     </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // form click login
    $(".click_login").on("click",function(){

        $(this).html("New Member! Then Sign Up");
        $(this).removeClass('click_login').addClass('click_signup');
        alert($(this).attr("class"));
        $("#form_submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login');         
    });

    // form click signup
    $(".click_signup").on("click",function(){

        $(this).html("Already signed up! Then  Login");
        $(this).removeClass('click_signup').addClass('click_login');
        $("#form_submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> signup');         
    });
   });
```

When I click on a link, it changes to Login button. But once it is updated via jquery, When I click on a link again, it doesn't change to new class to get Sign up button. New class is getting updated via jquery,but `on click` function doesn't trigger new class selector of the same element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 // form click signup
    $(document).on("click",".click_signup",function(){

        $(this).html("Already signed up! Then  Login");
        $(this).removeClass('click_signup').addClass('click_login');
        $("#form_submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> signup');         
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

USe $(document).on("click") event for dynamically added content:

```
    $(document).on("click",".click_login",function(){
        $(this).html("New Member! Then Sign Up");
        $(this).removeClass('click_login').addClass('click_signup');
        alert($(this).attr("class"));
        $("#form_submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login');         
    });

    // form click signup
    $(document).on("click",".click_signup",function(){

        $(this).html("Already signed up! Then  Login");
        $(this).removeClass('click_signup').addClass('click_login');
        $("#form_submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> signup');         
    });
```